# PHP cURL giving a different result than native cURL

Tags: php, curl

When I run the following cURL call natively I get an expected result.

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "https://XXXX" -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=YYYY
```

When I run the cURL call via PHP I get a different response.

```
$curl = curl_init('https://XXXX');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => 'YYYY'
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Is there any functional difference between the native call and the PHP approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that PHP's cURL doesn't trust the server's HTTPS certificate. Differently command line `curl` by default does.

The quick fix is to configure cURL to always trust the server:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

The proper fix is described here

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/